# How To Create One Text Box At Admin Panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

How To Create One Text Box At Admin Panel, And
If Text Box Has Enter Some Value That Display At Front End in All Products.

Comment: You need to create custom product attribute which can be added from backend & shown on the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a VERY small extension for this. Create a files (3 files only) with code shown below :

**/app/code/local/Company/Customtext/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Customtext>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_Customtext>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Company/Customtext/etc/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <general>
            <groups>
                <customtxt_group>
                    <label>Custom Text Box</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <custom_text_box>
                            <label>Textbox Label</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </custom_text_box>
                    </fields>
                </customtxt_group>
            </groups>
        </general>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**/app/etc/modules/Company_Customtext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Customtext>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company_Customtext>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now Clear cache. You can see a Textbox at `System > Configuration > General`

[image]

You can access the value of this text box by :

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig("general/customtxt_group/custom_text_box"); ?>
```

Comment: Thanx Anil Suthar

Answer (score 0):

You can Create configuration  in your admin section and use it on front-end there are many tutorial for this some of them are :-

http://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/

[Custom Magento System Configuration](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration)

[Custom Back-­End Configuration in Magento](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-back-end-configuration-in-magento--cms-23265)

[Add custom settings in Magento admin panel](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/01/30/add-custom-settings-in-magento-admin-panel/)